# Working of TAdvColumnGrid copy paste is not working with TEditCut/TEditCopy/TEditPaste

Tags: delphi, tms

I am facing some issue with copy paste options which I have added to the `TAdvColumnGrid`.
I am using Standard Actions of VCL components for `cut/copy/paste` as [TEditCut](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdActns.TEditCut), [TEditPaste](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdActns.TEditPaste), [TEditCopy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdActns.TEditCopy) assigned to `Popup menu`.

With these actions I can get the standard copy/paste working.
but when I select a cell which is not in `Edit mode` and try to `copy/cut/paste`.

The commands on Popup is not working for the operations.
but the keyboard shortcuts are working fine. for the same cell.

**Can anyone tell me what will be the problem?

Why Popup operations are working when the cell is in Edit mode

but not when it is in selection mode.**

I have tried with overriding the clipboard operations like `OnClipboardCopy` etc...
but the clipboard operations are triggered only when the cell is not in edit mode.

Comment: Are the menu items in the Popup connected to the same Actions? Have you tried putting a simple button on the form connected to the actions to see if it works like that ?

Comment: yes the action of the popup is connected to the same actions.
I tried it on sample application as well.